# split the given string into substring in c#

Tags: c#, split

I have a string variable that contains value :

`string str = "Res.No\1000-2023-2024\Bridge 1-2";` sometimes this str may be of `string str = "anju joseph bbbbbb : 1000";`
name and account code will be split to get
so now i want to getsplit this 1000 as accountcode, this 2023-2024 as accyr, Bridge 1-2 as class from above string.
whatever the string i want to split
i want to split and get the separated string the second one can be split into two.

```
   if (ObVoucher.Remark != null)
    {
        string remark = ObVoucher.Remark;

        splitRemark = remark.LastIndexOf('\\');
        if (splitRemark != -1)
        {
            DefAccYr = remark.Substring(splitRemark - 9, 9);
            Grade = remark.Substring(splitRemark + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my current code snippet i want to split second type of string if exists in same variable remarks

Comment: Use `else`. Is this [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2791540)? If you are writing actual code for commercial use then you should write a proper parser class.

Comment: I rarely do, but here I tend to suggest using Regex.

Comment: => https://regex101.com/r/t1DfzE/1 and https://regex101.com/r/CPnUQJ/1

Comment: I recommend using full names for variables and properties, instead of `DefAccYr`. Shortening it like that only makes it harder for you and your colleagues to understand. The compiler doesn't care how long a member's name is.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class StringSplitter {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "Res.No\\1000-2023-2024\\Bridge 1-2";
        String str2 = "anju joseph bbbbbb : 1000";
        
        parseString(str1);
        parseString(str2);
    }

    public static void parseString(String str) {
        // Check if the string contains the pattern with backslashes
        if (str.contains("\\")) {
            String[] parts = str.split("\\\\");

            String accountCode = parts[1].split("-")[0];
            String accYr = parts[1].split("-")[1] + "-" + parts[1].split("-")[2];
            String clazz = parts[2];

            System.out.println("Account Code: " + accountCode);
            System.out.println("Account Year: " + accYr);
            System.out.println("Class: " + clazz);
        } 
        // Check if the string contains the pattern with colon
        else if (str.contains(":")) {
            String[] parts = str.split(":");
            
            String name = parts[0].trim();
            String accountCode = parts[1].trim();
            
            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Account Code: " + accountCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, why my question got negative vote

Comment: I don't know about the question and I also did not dv on this answer, but: doing this via string split creates a _lot_ of garbage strings. That _may_ have been a reason. Sometimes, though, DVs just happen. Because people feel like it. I personally prefer to suggest improvements first.

Comment: See, my (working and tested) answer got dved, too. Someone doesn't like OP to have a working solution to his problem. :(